# Why doesn't IO::Socket::Async's emit a trailing "a"?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, raku

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get around the encoding of IO::Socket::Async, particularly the draw-backs described by [this](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Socket::Async#method_Supply):

> For example, if the UTF-8 encoding is being used and the last byte in the packet decoded to "a", this would not be emitted since the next packet may include a combining character that should form a single grapheme together. Control characters (such as \n) always serve as grapheme boundaries, so any text-based protocols that use newlines or null bytes as terminators will not need special consideration.

This is currently causing my sockets to omit the last character on messages, but I am not sure how to work around this. I tried to convert the `Connection` to a `Channel` then just feed a dumby `\n` into it, simulating end of input for the message, but that did not work. How can I work around this quirk in UTF-8 encoding?

Here is the MVP to reproduce this:

```
sub listen(Int $port) {
  react {
    whenever IO::Socket::Async.listen('0.0.0.0', $port) -> $connection {
      whenever $connection.Supply -> $data {
        say $data;
        $connection.print: $data;
      }
    }
  }
}

listen(9999);
```

Now if you hit port 9999 on your local machine with any data that does not end with `\n` you will see that the last byte is ignored.

Comment: show the code you are using ... have you tried using the `:bin` "adverb", so that the buffer is not treated as UTF-8 ?

Comment: @zentrunix I added some simple code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @zentrunix Looks like `:bin` worked, then I just take the `Buf[uint8]` and do `.decode.Str` and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: "Looks like `:bin` worked, then I just take the `Buf[uint8]` and do `.decode.Str` and it works like a charm." Unless the data is ASCII or similar, doing that means you're subverting Unicode encoding, so you'll get a mix of correct strings, (silently) incorrect strings, and decoding exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a "drawback"; it's just Raku reflecting how Unicode works. If you know you only need to handle ASCII or Latin-1, then specify that:

```
whenever $connection.Supply(:enc<ascii>) -> $data { # or :enc<latin-1>
    ...
}
```

If wanting to handle Unicode text, then it's necessary to deal with that fact that receiving, for example, the codepoint for the letter "a", does not give enough information to pass along a complete character, since the next codepoint received in the next packet might be a combining character, such as an acute accent to be placed on the "a". Note that a Raku `Str` is a character-level data structure (in other languages, strings are often bytes or codepoints, which creates different problems that are largely invisible to those only caring about English text!)

Any well-designed network protocol will provide a way to know when the end of the text content has been reached. Some protocols, such as HTTP, explicitly specify the byte length of the content, thus one can work a the byte level (`:bin`) and decode the result after seeing that many bytes. Others might use connection close or line breaks.

In conclusion, the string semantics or `IO::Socket::Async` (and elsewhere in Raku) aren't themselves a problem, but they may show up design problems in protocols.

Comment: Yeah I probably could have worded this better. Sorry about that. Your explanation was excellent and it helped me fully understand what's going on with UTF-8 and why it needs to be this way. Thank you!

Comment: It should be mentioned that using "UTF-8" in those descriptions is a bit misleading: This problem would occur in anything that supports all many/most/all Unicode codepoints (i.e. UTF-8, UTF-16 even UCS-2) and cares about grapheme boundaries (more things care about that than you'd think). It's entirely unrelated to UTF-8 as an encoding.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Agreed. It's not to do with UTF-8, it's to do with almost any Unicode encoding. I was surprised by the doc quote in the question, but then saw that the actual full doc sentence begins "For example, ", which was elided from the provided quote. The doc is fine -- providing an example is good -- but the problem is, as you emphasize, general to Unicode. I've just now edited the question (inserting the "For example, ") to try head off readers thinking this is about UTF-8.